# Get IP address of arriving data package

Tags: cocoa, networking

So I'm creating an input socket using

`CFSocketCreateWithSocketSignature (NULL, &signature, kCFSocketDataCallBack, receiveData, &socket_context);`

Within the receiveData function (that gets called properly) I'm trying to use the `CFDataRef address` parameter to find out the sender address of the this "package".

The IP address of the sender PC is at 192.168.1.2.

I'm using

`char buffer[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"incoming connection from: %s", inet_ntop(AF_INET, address, buffer, INET_ADDRSTRLEN)]);`

However I always get the 192.6.105.48 out of the log. What gives? I'm really not big on networking in Cocoa/C so any help / explanation is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a Category class of NSData that I've implemented for one of my projects. Using the toll-free bridge between CFDataRef and NSData you can use the following class.

```
@implementation NSData (Additions)

- (int)port
{
    int port;
    struct sockaddr *addr;

    addr = (struct sockaddr *)[self bytes];
    if(addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
        // IPv4 family
        port = ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in *)addr)->sin_port);
    else if(addr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
        // IPv6 family
        port = ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)addr)->sin6_port);
    else
        // The family is neither IPv4 nor IPv6. Can't handle.
        port = 0;

    return port;
}


- (NSString *)host
{
    struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr *)[self bytes];
    if(addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        char *address = 
          inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)addr)->sin_addr);
        if (address)
            return [NSString stringWithCString: address];
    }
    else if(addr->sa_family == AF_INET6) {
        struct sockaddr_in6 *addr6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)addr;
        char straddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(addr6->sin6_addr), straddr, 
            sizeof(straddr));
        return [NSString stringWithCString: straddr];
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the network-traffic is NAT/masqueraded on the way to the receiving end. The IP address you've given for the sender PC is in one of the RFC 1918 private/unrouted networks, whereas the IP address you're seeing is on a routed network-block.

Answer (score 0):

Well, barring programming mistakes and assuming Mac platform, check output of `ifconfig` on both machines, check the routing with `route get <IP>` from both machines; and all the way down to `tcpdump`.

By the way, having BSD layer really pays off on Mac - if you don't know how to use a tool just `man` it, like `man tcpdump`.